# Reference for implementing generalized likelihood ratio test to determine online whether time-series mean has shifted

Tags: time-series, likelihood-ratio, online-algorithms, change-point, structural-change

What is a reference that describes the "generalized likelihood ratio" test to determine **online** (i.e., meaning that we add an observation, then check, then add an observation, then check)  whether the mean of a time-series has shifted?

I need descriptions of algorithms to be implemented into computer code or reference implementations in python, C++, Java or anything really.

#### References

- Basseville, M., & Nikiforov, I. V. (1993). Detection of abrupt changes: theory and application (Vol. 104). Englewood Cliffs, NJ: Prentice Hall.